# delete where with implicit join in prisma

Tags: sqlite, next.js, prisma

I'm using prisma with sqlite in nextjs

Say I have two tables with an implicit join:

```
model Thing {
  objects Object[]
}
model Object {
  things Thing[]
}

How do I delete all Things that relates to the Object X? This doesn't work:

let object1 = prisma.object.findOne({...});

prisma.thing.deleteMany({
   where: {
      objects: object1 //nope!
   }
})
```